# map of map of structs and "assignment to entry in nil map"

Tags: go, hashmap

Here's an example where I get `assignment to entry in nil map` every time:
https://play.golang.org/p/LudJs0rVbs

To demonstrate what I'm trying to do, here's a naive version that causes 2 lookups to the database (you'll have to use your imagination on line 11):
https://play.golang.org/p/YZNFeMHyMs

Basically, I'm trying to do this:

```
things := make(map[string]map[string][]Struct)
...
stuff, there := things["first key"]
if !there {
    things["first key"] = getAMapOfStringToStructs()
}
doSomethingWith(things["first key"])
```

I've looked at the more [trivial examples of maps-of-maps here](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action) but I can't seem to map that to my problem.

Comment: The code you quote in the question is not like the code you linked to. In particular, here you `make` the `map[string]map[string][]Struct` but in the linked code you do not (as the other [dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2082673/dave) points out in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30243706/55504)). Such differences make questions confusing and difficult to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never did `make` on your `allEntries` map:

```
allEntries = make(map[string]map[string][]Thing)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ecdUU30FQT